# Persistent Regex Highlighting with Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I would like to have a special "comment" syntax with a special highlight.

For example:

I'm using Sublime Text 2. I found this Persistent Regex Highlight that seems to do exactly that, but I can't seem to figure out how to say....

```
" highlight anything between <!--x   and   x--> "
```

So far, I can get this basic string, "yo" to highlight, and I've tried a bunch of regex patterns but alas, I can't seen to get it! (haven't used regex too much and my search terms aren't specific enought)

```
{
    "regex": [{
        "pattern": "yo",
        "color": "ff0000",
        "ignore_case": false
    }]
}
```

This worked... but I don't understand it.

```
{
    "regex": [{
        "pattern": "(?<=<!--x).*?(?=x-->)",
        "color": "ff0000",
        "ignore_case": false
    }]
}
```

I will appreciate any direction. - @sheriffderek

https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight

Comment: what is d input and output

Comment: `(?<=<!--x).*?(?=x-->)`

Comment: You say this worked `(?<=<!--x).*?(?=x-->)`, but you don't understand it ? It uses a look behind and a look ahead, both of which are excluded from the match (ie. it won't be highlighted), but everything in between will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like you have a solution that works, but you're looking for an explanation? (If I'm misunderstanding the question here, please correct me).

Let's break down the regular expression into its components:

```
(?<=    <!--x    )    .    *?    (?=    x-->    )
```

- `<!--x` and `x-->` are literal strings, that appear directly in the text.
- `(?<= subpattern)` is known as a [lookbehind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookbehind) assertion. It requires that the text that is matched is preceded with subpattern, but it doesn't include the subpattern in the returned match text. In this case, it means that `<!--x` must occur before any highlighted text.
- `(?= subpattern)` is similarly known as a [lookahead](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookahead) assertion. Exact same thing, it requires that the subpattern go after the match, but not be included in it.
- `.` matches any character besides newline (which may or may not be what you want
- `*?` is a [non greedy repeat](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.non_greedy_repeats), which means it will match any number of the pattern before it (`.` in this case), but that if it has multiple choices of what to match will pick the shortest one that works.